# Why does order by clause in neo4j works differently than order by clause in SQL Server, on the same records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, neo4j, graph-databases, cql

I have created these records in table in SQL Server 2014.

```
Tom Cruise
Hunain
Anthony Hopkins
Aalishan
NULL
```

when I run

```
Select name from table1 order by name desc
```

then it returns:

```
Tom Cruise
Hunain
Anthony Hopkins
Aalishan
NULL
```

and when I run

```
Order by name asc
```

then it returns

```
NULL
Aalishan
Anthony Hopkins
Hunain
Tom Cruise
```

Well and good. I know, why.

But when I put the same records in neo4j's database and run this query:

```
Match(n:lblNames) return n.name order by n.name desc
```

then it returns:

```
 null
"aalishan"
"Tom Cruise"
"Hunain"
"Anthony Hopkins"
```

and for asc, it returns this

```
"Anthony Hopkins"
"Hunain"
"Tom Cruise"
"aalishan"
null
```

Why ?

Comment: At least the examples don't have the same records. One has `Aalishan` and other has `aalishan`

Comment: Capitalization matters ?

Comment: It does, if you're sorting with case sensitivity, and clearly you are if `Anthony` and `aalishan` are not sorted next to each other.

Answer (score 3):

Well that looks like Neo4j orders by uppercase first. Probably following ASCII ordering.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

From the documentation:

> 3.3.8.5. Ordering null When sorting the result set, null will always come at the end of the result set for ascending sorting, and first
>   when doing descending sort.

In your SQL Server setup, `A = a` for the purposes of ordering. So aalishan would be before Anthony.

In Neo4J, `A < a` for ordering, meaning uppercase comes before lowercase.  That is why Tom is before aalishan. As for the NULL, SQL Server puts NULL before anything when ascending, Neo4J does NULL at the end for ascending according to the docs.

Comment: apart from NULLs, why "aalishan" is at 2nd top in desc query result and "Anthony hopkins" at top in asc query result?

Comment: @Stacky Answer updated. You are using 'Aalishan' in SQL Server and 'aalishan' in Neo4j. Make the upper/lower case match and you will see the behavior I am describing.

Comment: thanks a lot. but how did you get there? I also ripped the whole google apart for this specific information but couldn't find. Where did you find this?

Comment: I spend entirely too much time using SQL Server and the Neo4j stuff is here: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/syntax/operators/#cypher-ordering